# Facebook API with iphone

Tags: objective-c, fbconnect, iphone-sdk-3.1

am new to iphone technology and i have been allocated on a project where i will be using an API of facebook so i have downloaded the facebook api from this link http://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

and i read its documentation where i got confused this is what i want to do:

1) The image from the UIImageView must be posted by the user to his facebook album, and that album will be selected by the user from his/her account.

2) The user can add comment on that photo which he/she added.

3)Logout logic

But when i draged and droped the FBConnect folder, in the documentation its said that i have to set the header but how and what to set in the header i am not aware of that, also when i tried to do login with the appID and appKey which i generated from Facebook developers its not helping me at all

Please help me out, am confused on this topic completely, if you provide me some snaps of the source code or some links then it would be very nice of you

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using ShareKit. It has made connecting to Facebook easier for some developers. You can find it at this link: http://www.getsharekit.com/